# Laravel 5.4 automatically redirec to home page when we use Validator

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //this method will be called when we signup for members


    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    return 'success';

}
```

this will automatically redirected to homepage of Laravel without any exception

i need a validation message there

eg. title is required

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has performed the redirect and stored the errors in the session. It is up to you to modify your view to display the errors that have been put in the session.

You can [read more about displaying validation errors in the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

Code example from that link: (add this to your view)

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks patricus , but when i making API i need this in json array format. So for now i am not using blade engine , only api

Comment: @ParthBhatti If you make an ajax request, or a request that has the `Accept: application/json` header, Laravel will automatically return a 422 response with a json object with the validation errors.